# Create a JavaScript lookup that compares user input to a large list of items

Tags: javascript, arrays, var

I have created a zip code lookup for users. When they enter their zip code, if their zip code is in the list, then it will report back that they are in one of our service areas. If their zip code is not in the list, then it will report back that service is not available in their area.

The example code I am using works well, but my challenge is that I am only using 3 zip codes but I need my list to include 100s of zip codes. Ideally I am hoping to refer to an external file that has a list of these zip codes but if not I can list them all in the script. I am open to suggestions. I am currently using switch. What is the best way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var zipcode = document.getElementById("myZipCode").value;
    var message;

  switch(zipcode) {
    case "85142":
    case "99999":
  case "88888":
        message = "Service is available for your location.";
        break;
    default:
        message = "Sorry your location is not available for service.<br />Click here to be notified once your location becomes available.";
  }

    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = message;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>  
<p>Enter your 5-digit Zip Code:</p>
<input id="myZipCode" type="text" maxlength="5">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Lookup</button>
<br />
<p id="response"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

My code is also available at: https://jsfiddle.net/aplanet/7ttb19h5/11/

Comment: Use a persistent store like a database, store as numbers, index the zip codes and your query will be blazing fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of browser support are you aiming for? If you need to support IE9 (`Set` needs IE11, and `.includes` will not work on IE at all), using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) would work well:

```js
window.coveredZips = ['77777', '88888', '99999'];
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var lookupButton = document.querySelector(".lookup-zip");
    var response = document.getElementById("response");
    var checkZipcodes = function() {
        var zipcode = document.getElementById("myZipCode").value;
        var message;

        if (window.coveredZips.indexOf(zipcode) > -1) {
            message = "Service is available for your location.";
        } else {
            message =
                "Sorry your location is not available for service.<br />Click here to be notified once your location becomes available.";
        }

        response.innerHTML = message;
    };
    lookupButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        checkZipcodes();
    });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

    <p>Enter your 5-digit Zip Code:</p>

    <input id="myZipCode" type="text" maxlength="5">

    <button class="lookup-zip">Lookup</button>
    <br />
    <p id="response"></p>

    <script src="coveredZips.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you view the REPL:
https://repl.it/@ryanpcmcquen/CheerfulWelllitDeveloper

You can see that the zip codes can live in their own file.

Comment: this is something I can work with. I am only partially familiar with 'window', but I will take some time to process all of this code. Thank you. I will post if I have questions.

Comment: @SteveHancock, `window.` just makes it a global variable. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: I just tested this code with approx. 2,000 zip codes (I didn't realize there would be this many), and it seems to be working well. I estimate I will have approx. 10,000 zip codes. Will this code continue to perform well with those numbers?

Comment: @SteveHancock, it should be fine with that amount of zip codes. If you find it is not suiting your needs once you reach 10,000, that would be the point where you start looking at other alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```
const zips = new Set(["85142", "99999", "88888"]);

console.log(zips.has("85142"));
```